# Talend BatchUpdateException not caught while using tOracleOutput

Tags: java, oracle, talend

I'm developing a job in which I transfer data from some tables to some others. Sometimes fields from the input are null and then Talend calls the method `oracle.jdbc.driver.setNull`. At one moment I got an Oracle error that isn't caught by Talend. The error is : `ORA-01401 value inserted too big for the column`. But at this moment Talend is trying to insert a Null value in a field which accept it.

I don't understand why I have the error and why Talend didn't catch it.

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in component tOracleOutput_1
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01401: valeur insérée trop grande pour colonne

at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:459)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4373)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.checkBindTypes(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3650)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNull(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1435)
at maxmigtransformation.t_dm_all_0_1.T_DM_ALL.tOracleInput_1Process(T_DM_ALL.java:11910)
at maxmigtransformation.t_dm_all_0_1.T_DM_ALL.runJobInTOS(T_DM_ALL.java:30394)
at maxmigtransformation.t_dm_all_0_1.T_DM_ALL.main(T_DM_ALL.java:29916)
```

Here is a screenshot of the job:

[image: Talend Job]

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand what you're asking here. Are you saying that when trying to insert a null into a nullable column Oracle is throwing the `ORA-01401` error? I'm assuming you've ran this job with server side tracing/logs on to see exactly what's causing the problem? Are you wanting Talend to do something with this error and then carry on? The default behaviour for this would be to back out of a commit and that's what Talend appears to be doing.

Comment: I have 2 problems : I don't understand why there is the Oracle error and I don't understand why talend didn't catch the error. I can't have access to the logs of the database.

Comment: I'd guess that the error is actually being caused by what it reckons it is: you're trying to insert/update a value that is too big for the field. Check the data you're inserting/updating and the field lengths in the table your'e inserting/updating into. If you disable the "die on error" check box for the component then Talend should catch the error and carry on but in reality you are better off fixing your target table or the source data. If you have no access to change the target table you can substring your data to safely truncate it.

Comment: I can see in the stack trace that the error is caused by the call of the setNull method so I don't understand how it is possible to have the error. The field which have the error is a Date and both input and output tables have the same format for their fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my probleme. The stacktrace was not indicating the good line number. 
Using the reject link I saw the problem wasn't on the line the stacktrace show.

There was effectively a field that was too short for the amount of data I wanted to insrt into it but not the one the stacktrace shown. I don't know why the error say line 11910.

To figure out I used the reject link and then I checked evry field by hand to figure out where the error was.

Comment: So was the error because the data was too big for the column? It would be more useful for others who come across this error if you edited your post to show what you did to fix it rather than just how you diagnosed the real problem (although this is useful as well).